# When considering weak limit of measures, why do we acknowledge only the absolutely continuous parts?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I ran across the following in one of my books:

Let $(X,T, \mu)$ be a measure preserving transformation and let $U(f)=f(Tx)$ for $f \in L^2(X,\mu)$.  The spectral measure $\sigma_{f,g}$ is determined by the equations

$\hat{\sigma}_{f,g}(-k)=\int_0^1e^{2 \pi i k \omega} d \sigma_{f,g}(\omega)=\langle U^kf,g \rangle$.

The claim is that $\sigma_{f,g}=weak^* -\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \langle \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{- 2 \pi i n \omega}U^nf,\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{- 2 \pi i n \omega}U^ng \rangle $

where the right hand side is considered to be the $weak^*$ limit of absolutely continuous measures with the given density.  My question is why do we only consider the absolutely continuous measures?  The proof simply takes the fourier coefficients of the right hand side and shows that they tend towards $\hat{\sigma}_{f,g}$, using the fact that $\hat{(e^{-2 \pi i n \omega}) d \omega}(-k)=\delta_{k,n}$.  I'd also like to know if any issues come up if the spectral measure $\sigma_{f,g}$ has any atoms.